# Different type of properties in Gradle?

Tags: properties, gradle, system, environment

What are the different type of properties in Gradle and what it is the difference of using them.

From what I know there are : system properties, environment properties and ONLY properties( extra properties ) declared with **-D**, **-P** and with **ext**. But if there are more types and when is good to use all of them.

Please give examples.

Answer (score 1):

System properties and project properties are used to pass arguments from the command line. They are very similar, and it doesn't really matter which one you use. (The former is a Java feature, the latter a Gradle feature.) Extra properties are used for extending the build model. In other words, you can add new properties to existing objects, and other build scripts will be able to see them.

The [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) has more information on these concepts.